# Is the Set of Distances Between a Finite Open Subset and a Closed Subset of a Metric Space Closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In order to be as clear as possible, I've taken the liberty of TeXing (Tikzing?) up the sort of image in question.
[image]

Here, $\gamma$ is some path in the complex plane, the disk $\Delta(z_0,2r)\subset{U}$ where $U=\mathbb{C}\sim|\gamma|$ and $|\gamma|\subset\Delta(0,s)$.

I ask this because a proof in my book says that, if $z$ lies in the punctured disk $\Delta^*=\Delta^*(z_0,r)$ (i.e., the set given open disk of radius $r$ less $\{z_0\}$) and $\zeta$ on $|\gamma|$, then $|\zeta-z_0|\ge{r}$ and $|\zeta-z|\ge{r}$.

What puzzles me is the use of the $\ge$ symbols, as it seems to imply that the set defined as the distance between the boundary of $\Delta(z_0,2r)$ and the set of points in $\Delta^*$ is closed, as it contains all of its limit points.

I cannot justify this, as $\gamma$ is permitted to be within $2r$ of $z_0$, but $z$ cannot be within $r$ of the boundary of the disk $\Delta(z_0,2r)$. Certainly any point located a distance $r$ away from $z_0$ is an accumulation point of the punctured disk, but not an accumulation point contained within it. Correct?

Or is it enough to say that, given some sequence $\langle{z_n}\rangle$ such that $|z_n-z_0|\rightarrow{r}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the value $r$ must be included in the set of distances between $\Delta^*$ and $2r$?

Comment: Your title perhaps does not say what you wish it to say. In the complex plane, the only "open and closed subsets" are the empty set and the whole plane.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, bad grammar, bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness helps simplify this. Distance is a continuous function of two variables. So, $d(\xi,\eta)$ is continuous as $\xi$ varies over $\gamma$ and $\eta$ varies independently over $\Delta(z_0,r)$. But the Cartesian product $\gamma \times \Delta(z_0,r)$ is compact, because $\gamma$ is compact and $\Delta(z_0,r)$ is compact. The continuous image of a compact set is compact. So the set of values of $d(\xi,\eta)$ is compact, and therefore is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Maybe my definition of compact is faulty in someway, but I thought that an open set, $\Delta^*(z_0,r)$, couldn't be compact? The only closed set I am considering here is the boundary of the disk $\Delta(z_0,2r)$?

Comment: I made the assumption that your notation $\Delta^*(z_0,r)$ is a closed ball, and therefore a closed set, because of your picture which shows it surrounded by a solid circle, which I assumed to be part of the set.

Comment: If that assumption is unwarranted, then you can run into trouble defining the concept of distance between two sets, because the minimum of distance between a point in one set and a point in the other set might not exist. But as long as you use "infimum" instead of "minimum" in your definition of distance between two sets, the definition of distance works well for bounded sets. Then you can just replace each of those bounded sets by its closure and use my argument.

Comment: OK, thank you very much, I apologize for the confusion with the picture!